# How do you return a POST message exactly the way it was received in Flask (meaning no encoding changes)

Tags: flask, encoding, utf-8, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been fighting with Paypals API, and more specifically I've been trying to implement IPN (instant payment notifications) into my flask app. I have gotten it to the point where it works as long as I don't include any special characters. Unfortunately my last name is Engström...

The way it works is that paypal sends a bunch of parameters to you, which you are then supposed to send back **exactly** the way they came to you, with the addition of a parameter specifying `cmd=_notify-validate`

My current code is essentially:

```
@app.route("/paypal_ipn", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def paypal_ipn_listener():
 
    # Returning message as-is with the notify-validate request
    raw_data = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + request.get_data()
    response = requests.post(VERIFY_URL, params=raw_data, verify=True)
    response.raise_for_status()

    # See if PayPal confirms the validity of the IPN received
    if response.text == 'VERIFIED':
        print(OKGREEN + "Verified IPN response received." + ENDC)

    elif response.text == 'INVALID':
        # Don't trust
        print(FAIL + "Invalid IPN response." + ENDC)
    else:
        print("Some other response.")
        print(response.text)
    return ""
```

And this code in fact works fine so long as my last name is Engstrom rather than Engström when paying for something.

**My troubleshooting so far:**

Apparently Paypal uses the windows-1252 encoding per default. I however changed for it to use the utf-8 encoding using this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303635/5331467, however that didn't do anything when I made a payment, and I'm sticking with the [IPN simulator tool](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator) for now, which is stuck with windows-1252

If I print `request.form` I get among other things `ImmutableMultiDict([('last_name', u'Engstr\ufffdm'')` which notably looks the same for ä and ö, which at least tells me it sees no distinction between them

The stuff that's in request.get_data() is

> payment_type=instant&payment_date=15%3A08%3A30%20Jan%2028%2C%202022%20PST&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Engstr%F6m&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=474083376&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=A8Vpc0Ws5acpR3s0gcM6u4Qtk1utA8eY7wJKy6n.AkPJ6RHIQeSSmBzL

where it says **&last_name=Engstr%F6m**

Now I don't know if what I want is for it to actually have the right encoding when being sent, or if theres some way for me to ensure it never touches the encoding anyways.

**TL;DR

Taking an incoming POST message and sending it straight back in Flask still screws up the formatting somehow.**

Comment: `\ufffd` is the replacement character. It most probably means some process earlier has already given up on the (misinterpreted?) "ö" and replaced it with "�".

Comment: Are you using Python 2 still? The `u` prefix in `u'Engstr\ufffdm'` looks like it. Besides Python 2 having reached its end of life some time ago (which means it isn't receiving security updates anymore!), also encoding stuff is more complicated and error-prone compared to Python 3.

Comment: Thank you! That simplifies troubleshooting significantly!

Comment: I popped on over to python3 instead (which was a breeze). Now Flask gives me request.get_data() as bytes instead (b'last_name=Engstr%F6m'), which I figured sounds nice and unencoded. However, just sending those bytes straight back without touching them still isn't enough. Something changes somewhere along the way and I can't figure out what.

Comment: IT WORKED!

After switching to python 3, the testing still didn't work, since paypal uses windows-1252 for that, but I tried making a real live payment that now should use UTF-8 and that did in fact work, printing my name as b'Engstr%C3%B6m'.

This means that some magic goes on either before the data extraction, or I suppose more likely in `requests.post(VERIFY_URL, params=raw_data, verify=True)` that changes the encoding. But it was fine now.

Maybe p3 uses utf8 at some place where p2.7 doesn't...

Answer (score -2):

Your first mistake is using IPN for anything at all, it's 20 years old and quite clunky. Don't use IPN, and if you are going to complain that a 20-year-old piece of technology is difficult to integrate from scratch with current web stacks, well, yes it is.

Today's PayPal integrations use REST APIs and the JS SDK. For one-time payments the capture response should be all you need -- however in the rare event that you need asynchronous notifications of later events such as refunds, use Webhooks.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I want flask and python since it integrates well with my RPi GPIO project. 

And its not like it doesn't work, it works just fine with only the few lines of code above so long as you don't have weird characters

Comment: The above applies to any environment, including flask and python.

Comment: Right, but you'd still need to set up (and understand) o-auth which is a hassle for a noob, understand this way harder documentation and there are no easy, short youtube tutorials to follow.

For my hobby use, which is literally dispensing shots of vodka into my friends mouths, this is super simple, straightforward and easy, except for python changing some encoding and me wanting to change it back

Comment: Obtaining the API access token is abstracted by https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK , `pip install paypal-checkout-serversdk`.  Can't get much easier than that